# Ошибка при подключении бд

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysqli

При подключении к бд выдаёт ошибку "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'gallium_quasar'@'ip-200-111-142-5.pools.atnet.ru' (using password: YES)" Все данные ввожу верно (банально копирую их с сайта, где всё работает).
Подключаю через библиотеку "mysql".

Сам код:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host", 
    port: "3306",
    user: "user",
    database: "database",
    password: "password"

});

conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
    }
});
```

Comment: а что в host и в user написано?

Comment: @nörbörnën в host вписан сервер для внешних подключений взятый(взятый с места хранения бд), в user название бд(оно соответствует с именем пользователя)

Comment: этот скрипт работает, если запустить его на сервере с которого скопированы реквизиты подключения

Comment: @nörbörnën, а можете тогда подсказать, как подключить бд к стороннему проекту на node js?

Comment: прошу прощения, мой предыдущий комментарий был вопросом: этот скрипт работает, если запустить его на сервере с которого скопированы реквизиты подключения? на самом деле в вашем вопросе слишком мало информации, чтобы вам как-то помочь так что лучшим советом будет - проработать все варианты решений проблемы, которые можно найти в [goolge](https://www.google.com/search?q=ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR%3A+Access+denied+for+user)